# LibreOffice Calc Macro - Como capturar intervalos selecionados

Tags: macro, libreoffice

Estou criando uma macro no LibreOffice Calc e preciso de uma maneira de selecionar alguns intervalos de células não consecutivos, e capturar quais são esses intervalos selecionados. Por exemplo, quero selecionar os intervalos "A1:A10", "C5:C13", "H7:H9" e poder capturar essas três strings, pra poder aplicar alguma ação onde selecionei. Já criei a macro abaixo, pra poder fazer um "replace" nas células selecionadas, mas ela só funciona num único intervalo.
Agradeço qualquer dica.

https://pastebin.com/4BtGjuVc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer. Caso alguém se interesse, segue a implementação:

https://pastebin.com/3EX0f2yA

Answer (score 0):

O Calc não seleciona seleções multliplas, faça 3 macros. e interligue-as.